# How to resolve RFC6797 vulnerability issue in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, hsts

**Hi i am working on spring boot application currently RFC6797 (HSTS) security vulnerability reported in my microservice application.
I have added below header in response in filter class**

`response.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains");` 
But still the security scan reported HSTS vulnerability.
Note I also tried configure hsts in spring security config as well but no luck

```
httpSecurity.headers()
     .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
     .includeSubDomains(true)
     .preload(true)
     .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Can you show the details of the vulnerability? Is your SSL/TLS certificate valid?

Comment: RFC6797/HSTS is a feature for improving security, not a vulnerability.

Comment: HSTS missing from HTTPS sever(rfc6797).

Comment: Are you using any reverse proxy? What tool is showing you that vulnerability? Can you show an example HTTPs request to the application which includes the sent response headers (e.g. using `curl -i`)?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CEB0836807AF05CA294D55B093F42931; Path=/npbc; Secure; HttpOnly
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains ; preload
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 111
< Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2022 07:55:52 GMT

Comment: these are the response headers for curl req to https

Comment: HSTS seems working - what makes you think you have a "vulnerability"? Aside from that, you might not want to use HSTS preloading until you are absolutely sure everything works...

Comment: Ok , did we need to set the response header for http as well? Or https is enough?

Comment: Did we need to redirect the http requests to https?

Comment: HSTS is only valid for HTTP. A redirect from HTTP to HTTPs is typically recommended.